# Youtrack query: Find issues that depend on my open issues

Tags: youtrack

Basically the title says it all:
In Youtrack I need to know which tasks depend on the tasks assigned to me.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:
`Assignee: me has: {Is required for}`

Comment: Then you need to open them and check under Linked Issues which tasks are them required for.